# How to authenticate with azure container registry using cert-based service principal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-container-registry

I'm following the below tutorial to push docker image to my ACR. I'm authenticating using AAD service principal. The article mentions the steps to authenticate when the AAD service principal has a password, mine has a certificate not a password.

article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal#feedback

I tried converting the cert pfx to bytes then base64 encode it and pass it as password to docker login command but that didn't work, I got authentication error.

Comment: Checking the docs my first guess would be that it is simply not supported. At least not via the `docker login` command.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at the [description](https://docs.docker.com/ee/dtr/user/access-dtr/). Or you can find other messages about it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://github.com/Azure/acr/blob/master/docs/AAD-OAuth.md
The steps involve using the AAD token to get an access token from ACR, then use that one to pull/push using docker CLI